# Yii2 query returns 2 rows, model only one

Tags: mysql, activerecord, yii2

Within Yii2 I use the following code in my controller:

```
$licenses = License::find()
        ->select('`license`.*, `customer`.*')
        ->orderBy('added_on')
        ->innerJoin('customer', '`customer`.`id` = `license`.`customer_id`')
        ->where([
            'active' => '1'
        ])
        ->andWhere(['not', ['customer_id' => null]])
        ->andWhere("last_changed > last_confirmed")
        ->all();

    return $this->render('not-handled', [
        'licenses' => $licenses
    ]);
```

Which outputs the following query (from the Yii2 debug toolbar):

```
SELECT `license`.*, `customer`.* FROM `license` INNER JOIN `customer` ON `customer`.`id` = `license`.`customer_id` WHERE ((`active`='1') AND (NOT (`customer_id` IS NULL))) AND (last_changed > last_confirmed) ORDER BY `added_on`
```

Running this query on the database returns 2 rows, which is correct. However, when dumping the data from $licenses, it only returns one row. When I change the customer_id in the licences table, it however does return both rows. So somewhere Yii2 drops one row, even though the query returns the correct values.

I've searched a lot, however I can't find any solution for the problem. Thank you in advance!

**EDIT 1**

Within my License model, I have the following function. Removing this function still causes the same problem, however it gets the other row (it's reversed). Still one row though.

```
public function getCustomer()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Customer::className(), ['id' => 'customer_id']);
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Here are the dumped tables. When I change the customer_id on rows with id 3 and 4 to something else (in the dump they are both 2, once I change either one to another value) it does return both rows.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `customer`;
CREATE TABLE `customer` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(70) NOT NULL,
  `streetname` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `house_number` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `postal_code` varchar(7) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `customer` VALUES (1,'Dummyuser1','Dummystreet1',1,'Dummtcity1','1111 DE','dummy1@hotmail.com','dummy1','dummy1'),(2,'Dummyuser2','Dummestreet2',2,'Dummycity2','2222 RR','dummy2@hotmail.com','dummy2','dummy2');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `license`;
CREATE TABLE `license` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `license` varchar(29) NOT NULL,
  `added_on` datetime NOT NULL,
  `license_activated_on` datetime NOT NULL,
  `last_changed` datetime NOT NULL,
  `last_confirmed` datetime NOT NULL,
  `requested_by` varchar(70) NOT NULL,
  `changed_by` varchar(70) NOT NULL,
  `active` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `customer_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `costs` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `article_type` enum('1','3') NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `invoice_number` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `invoice_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `license_UNIQUE` (`license`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `license` VALUES (1,'DFDFD-DFDFD-DFDFD-QASDF','2016-04-22 17:06:57','0000-00-00 00:00:00','0000-00-00 00:00:00','0000-00-00 00:00:00','Wessel','','1',0,30,'1',0,'0000-00-00 00:00:00'),(2,'ABCDE-FGHIJ-KLMNO-PQRST','2016-04-22 17:36:25','0000-00-00 00:00:00','2016-04-22 17:36:25','2016-04-22 18:00:00','Wesel','Wessel2','1',1,400,'3',34342,'2016-04-22 17:36:25'),(3,'QWERT-YUIOP-ASDFG-HJKLZ','2016-04-23 10:51:19','2016-04-23 10:51:19','2016-04-23 10:51:19','0000-00-00 00:00:00','Wessel Dummy','','1',2,40,'1',0,'0000-00-00 00:00:00'),(4,'QWERT-YUIOP-ASDFG-AAAAA','2016-04-23 10:51:19','2016-04-23 10:51:19','2016-04-23 10:51:19','0000-00-00 00:00:00','Wessel Dummy1','d','1',2,40,'1',0,'0000-00-00 00:00:00'),(5,'ABCDE-FGHIJ-DD4NO-PQRST','2016-04-22 17:36:25','0000-00-00 00:00:00','2016-04-22 17:36:25','2016-04-22 18:00:00','Wesel','Wessel2','1',2,400,'3',34342,'2016-04-22 17:36:25'),(7,'DFDFD-DFDFD-DFDFD-QQQQQ','2016-04-22 17:06:57','0000-00-00 00:00:00','0000-00-00 00:00:00','0000-00-00 00:00:00','Wessel','','1',0,30,'1',0,'0000-00-00 00:00:00');
```

Comment: Are you sure the all the result form dump is visible ?  if the dump is huge the browser don't show all the result..

Comment: There are only 6 rows in the license table, and 2 rows in the customer table. The query only returns 2 rows. So that shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: I have post a suggestion  .. let me know

Comment: Could you show the customer relation in your License model?

Comment: @topher I've added it to the main post. See EDIT 1.

Comment: __When I change the `customer_id` in the licences table, it however does return both rows__ Could you dump the database and the result of your query? Also indicate which customer id you change and to what in order to get both rows.

Comment: @topher please see EDIT 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an answer but a suggestion for check the problem origin

Could be that the query generatedv by activeQuery in not the same you sue in db console

try obtain the command  use by yii2 and check if is the same  as you expected

```
$dbcommand = License::find()
    ->select('`license`.*, `customer`.*')
    ->orderBy('added_on')
    ->innerJoin('customer', '`customer`.`id` = `license`.`customer_id`')
    ->where([
        'active' => '1'
    ])
    ->andWhere(['not', ['customer_id' => null]])
    ->andWhere("last_changed > last_confirmed")->createCommand();
```

try

```
 echo $dbCommand->sql;
```

Try

```
foreach($licenses as $key=> $value) {
  var_dump($value->license );
}
```

how many result you obtain ? if you obatin a single row this is related to the fact  you are using License::find() and the License part of the query return a model only because this part is the same for both the records

Then try using a command

```
use Yii;

$query= \Yii::$app->db->createCommand(
  "SELECT `license`.*, `customer`.* 
   FROM `license` 
   INNER JOIN `customer` ON `customer`.`id` = `license`.`customer_id` 
   WHERE ((`active`='1') 
   AND (NOT (`customer_id` IS NULL))) 
   AND (last_changed > last_confirmed) 
   ORDER BY `added_on`;");

$licenses = $query->queryAll();
```

Comment: This might be a stupid question, (I'm still quite new to Yii2), but how do I obtain the command?

Comment: It doesn't show any query when I var_dump the $dbcommand var. The array is filled with basic information (such as connection data).

Comment: This echo's the following: `SELECT `license`.*, `customer`.* FROM `license` INNER JOIN `customer` ON `customer`.`id` = `license`.`customer_id` WHERE ((`active`=:qp0) AND (NOT (`customer_id` IS NULL))) AND (last_changed > last_confirmed) ORDER BY `added_on``

Comment: Performing this query  in you db console (adding the proper value to the param )  you have the same result that your select ? .. are the two query different?

Comment: There is no change indeed. The queries are the exact same, and give the same result.

Comment: Well have you tried for debug a a foreach on the $licenses models  for see the result ..i have udpdate the answer  .. for  a suggestion

Comment: I've already dumped the $licenses var. Both in the controller and in the view. They both only return one result. So the variable somewhere get's dumped by Yii2 in the query builder part.

Comment: Could be that the License part of the result set is the same ?

Comment: The license part is the same yes, as it get's the data based on the customer_id. So when they have the same customer_id, the join get's the same data from the customer table.

Comment: Then i have update the answer using createCommand instead of activeRecord .. let me know

Comment: This returns a "Class 'app\controllers\Yii' not found" error. My apologies - as I said, I'm quite new. However, as far as I understand your comment, there is no way to do this without in fact a  "raw query"?

Comment: for what i know at the moment  seems that the use of raw query is the simplest way

Comment: Alright. Any fix for the error? I hope someone finds a way to do it with the query builder.

Comment: Try using  `\Yii::$app->db->.... `  and add use Yii;  .. i have update the answer

Comment: This has fixed the problem, and it indeed works. However I do hope someone can find a way to do it with the querybuilder, as it looks more organised. Thank you a lot.

Comment: @WesselV  the problem is related to the fact the queryBuilder based on active Record License is not the better way  for manage your query .. you should evalute  how Yii2 manage relations  .using getter in models ..

Comment: Any tips for me to get started on improving it? Always eager to learn, however I can't find any good leads.

Comment: The starting point is http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-index.html  (working with database)  and Relations .. also could be  the Yii2 wiki  like this http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/621/filter-sort-by-calculated-related-fields-in-gridview-yii-2-0/

Answer (score -1):

for debugging ActiveQuery i would suggest this:

```
$licenses = License::find()
        ->select('`license`.*, `customer`.*')
        ->orderBy('added_on')
        ->innerJoin('customer', '`customer`.`id` = `license`.`customer_id`')
        ->where([
            'active' => '1'
        ])
        ->andWhere(['not', ['customer_id' => null]])
        ->andWhere("last_changed > last_confirmed")
//        ->all()
;

var_dump($licenses->prepare( Yii::$app->db->queryBuilder )->createCommand()->rawSql);
```

btw, i am guessing that you have assigned 1 license for 2 customers, so you get 1 license model and 2 customers assigned to the same license.

Comment: For the debugging part, they've explained above already. And no it's the other way around, 2 licenses have 1 customer assigned.